# Calculate time difference between two dates SQL 2012 - Format/Convert as TIME for SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, time, ssrs-2012

I'm hoping someone can help. I have read a couple of questions / answers on this subject and have been able to replicate some of the solutions, however I am struggling to format my output as a Time format so I can aggregate in SSRS Reporting, I currently get an #Error. I have managed to find the time difference between two dates using the below code however the field is VARCHAR, is there a way to convert time or INT so I can format in SSRS?

```
,CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),DATEDIFF (SECOND, FFP.[CreatedDate], FFP.[LastModifiedDate])/3600)+':'+
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),DATEDIFF (SECOND, FFP.[CreatedDate], FFP.[LastModifiedDate])%3600/60)+':'+
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),(DATEDIFF(SECOND, FFP.[CreatedDate], FFP.[LastModifiedDate])%60))+'.'+
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),(DATEDIFF(SECOND, FFP.[CreatedDate], FFP.[LastModifiedDate])%1000))     AS [Test]
```

Example Dates and Output CreatedDate = 2016-10-10 10:53:26.0829077
Last Modified Date = 2016-10-10 11:06:09.2670000 Output = 0:12:43.763. Is there a way to convert this to a time field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SSRS you can convert date strings to datetime objects using `CDate()` function.

For example:

```
=FORMAT(
DATEADD(
  DateInterval.Second,
  DATEDIFF(DateInterval.Second,CDATE("2016-10-10 10:53:26.0829077"),
    CDATE("2016-10-10 11:06:09.2670000")
  ),
  CDATE("00:00:00"))
,"HH:mm:ss")
```

In this case it calculates the difference between both dates in seconds, then sums that difference in seconds to `00:00:00`, and finally format to `HH:mm:ss`.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Brill this could work for me! I will give it a go and vote accordingly soon! :)